# The config.hpp.in file shows error in vs code even though I installed CMake Extension

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I have `config.hpp.in` file that has an app version, used to generate `config.hpp` by the cmake. it works fine when built by the cmake but the vs code shows an error shown in the following image,

[image]

My `CMakeLists.tst` shown in below

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(clipbirdesk VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{QT_CMAKE_DIR})

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  Widgets
  Network
)

configure_file(
  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/config/config.hpp.in
  ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/config/config.hpp
)

qt_standard_project_setup()
qt_add_executable(clipbirdesk
  main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(clipbirdesk
  PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets
  PRIVATE Qt6::Network)

target_include_directories(clipbirdesk
  PUBLIC ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
```

How to remove the error from vs code, Note: I have installed cmake extension in vs code

Edit 1:

```
Error: command-line error: language modes specified are incompatible C/C++ (1027)
```

Comment: Why does it matter? If the code compiles just ignore it and move on?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I like the attitude of OP though. Too often I see developers ignore warnings that only will bite back later.

Comment: what does the problem say in its description?

Comment: When post a question on Stack Overflow, it is a good policy to add the **error message** in the **textual** form.

Comment: I have edited the question, can you check again?